# Admin panel displays a blank page

Tags: php, magento, error-handling, admin, magento-1.9

I have a website in Magento 1.9.3.6 and when I want to enter on the admin panel displays a blank page, without nothing on it. I can't see any error and my browser console is empty. I looked in **exception.log** and **system.log** files but there is no error. How can I enable the errors to show on the admin page to see why the page is not loading? And what could be the solution to my problem? 
I wrote this on my **index.php**:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

But nothing happened, it doesn't display any error!

Can anyone help with my problem? Thank you

Comment: Change the settings in your php.ini file

Comment: Ok, so the problem was a conflict that was created when I edited my custom theme from admin panel. I found the problem because I remembered that I made a change and I reverse it and now it's working!